# When does one write a number as words and when as digits?

Tags: style, numbers

I think I heard somewhere a rule that says "numbers up to twelve should be spelled out, numbers above can be written numerically" but not only do I not remember if that was exactly how the rule went, I'm fairly sure the source wasn't really reliable.

So, can you tell me whether - in a common text, not legalese, not calculations, nothing unusual - I should use digits or letters? Is it true you should write "eleven" but "13" in a literary text?

Also, I'm pretty sure that, even if it's true, there must be exceptions. If I'm right, can you name them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this question, I'd go to *The Chicago Manual of Style*.  Their general rule is, for non-technical contexts, "spell[] out whole numbers from zero through one hundred and certain round multiples of those numbers."

Exceptions using digits:

- dates: 8 January 2012
- numbers referring to parts of a book: table 23 on page 4; chapter 11
- volumes, distances, other physical quantities: 15 kilometers; 6 cubic feet; 3 tonnes; 10 degrees of arc; ... (but if the context is non-technical, words can be used)

Exceptions using words:

- when the value is approximate: seventy-five million
- at the beginning of a sentence: Two hundred fifty visitors ... (but sometimes it's advisable to rephrase, such as if a year starts a sentence)

The actual list in *Chicago* is much longer and more complicated.  *Chicago* also recognizes the practice of using digits rather than words for any value ten or greater.  Usage is really rather flexible -- so consider the context you're working in, and try to be consistent.

Comment: The British tabloid newspaper the _Sun_, owned by Rupert Murdoch, was famous (or notorious) at one time for its daily full-page pictures of topless young women. They always appeared at the same place in the paper, and they became known as 'page three girls'.

Answer (score 7):

There is a nice article [10 Rules for Writing Numbers and Numerals](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/10-rules-for-writing-numbers-and-numerals/)

The main rules:

- Spell small numbers out. (My rule: Up to twelve - thirteen is a composed word and *long*)
- Don’t start a sentence with a numeral.
- Centuries and decades should be spelled out.
- If the number is rounded or estimated, spell it out

Form another [source](http://www.grammarbook.com/numbers/numbers.asp)

- Be consistent within a category.

Comment: Keep in mind this is only 1 of who knows how many sources.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard different numbers from multiple sources on this matter. I've seen cutoffs of 10 and 20 and 100. I'm not sure if there is a fixed standard.