# Which one is the better choice of writing numbers?

Tags: numbers

In a scholarly paper, which of the following is the right way of writing down numbers?

> 1. The country is **the first** in the region, **fourth** in the continent, and
>      **sixteenth** globally.
> 2. The country is **1st** in the region, **4th** in the continent, and **16th**
>      globally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First, Second, Third, Fourth or 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th? One, Two, Three or 1, 2, 3?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/first-second-third-fourth-or-1st-2nd-3rd-4th-one-two-three-or-1-2-3)

Comment: As with many details about written English, there is no universal "better". For a scholarly paper, there will almost certainly be an official [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) either from your sponsoring institution or from whichever journal you are submitting to. We can argue that you should use one form or the other, but ultimately your editors and your readers will be the ones judging your output.

Comment: @choster Right. Is "1st" correct, or "the 1st"?